# Problems building an html5 version of a haxe nme project

Tags: html, flash, haxe, nme

I have tried to build an html5 canvas version of the [nme-runnermark](https://github.com/elsassph/nme-runnermark), but without any significant success. The flash version builds without any problems.
I get the following stack of errors:

```
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/utils/ByteArray.hx:22: characters 46-47 : Property initialization is not allowed
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/utils/ByteArray.hx:24: characters 27-28 : Member variable initialization is not allowed outside of class constructor
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/utils/ByteArray.hx:26: characters 29-30 : Member variable initialization is not allowed outside of class constructor
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/utils/ByteArray.hx:30: characters 33-38 : Member variable initialization is not allowed outside of class constructor
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/display/DisplayObject.hx:833: characters 28-52 : Cannot access to private field nmeValidateMatrix
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/text/TextField.hx:905: lines 905-909 : Field get_width has different visibility (public/private) than superclass one
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/text/TextField.hx:236: lines 236-262 : Field nmeGetObjectUnderPoint has different visibility (public/private) than superclass one
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/display/DisplayObject.hx:610: characters 3-20 : Cannot access to private field nmeSetFlag
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/text/TextField.hx:265: lines 265-302 : Field nmeRender has different visibility (public/private) than superclass one
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/text/TextField.hx:740: characters 3-29 : Cannot access to private field nmeInvalidateBounds
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/text/TextField.hx:916: characters 3-29 : Cannot access to private field nmeInvalidateBounds
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/text/TextField.hx:912: lines 912-935 : Field set_width has different visibility (public/private) than superclass one
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/display/DisplayObject.hx:519: characters 3-43 : Cannot access to private field nmeGetInteractiveObjectStack
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/display/DisplayObject.hx:431: characters 3-43 : Cannot access to private field nmeGetInteractiveObjectStack
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/display/DisplayObject.hx:446: characters 4-24 : Cannot access to private field nmeDispatchEvent
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/display/DisplayObject.hx:478: characters 4-24 : Cannot access to private field nmeDispatchEvent
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/display/Bitmap.hx:62: lines 62-88 : Field nmeGetObjectUnderPoint has different visibility (public/private) than superclass one
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/display/Bitmap.hx:91: lines 91-148 : Field nmeRender has different visibility (public/private) than superclass one
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/display/DisplayObject.hx:1110: characters 3-34 : Cannot access to private field nmeInvalidateBounds
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/display/DisplayObject.hx:1116: characters 3-30 : Cannot access to private field nmeInvalidateBounds
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/display/DisplayObject.hx:1301: characters 4-30 : Cannot access to private field nmeInvalidateBounds
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/display/DisplayObject.hx:1328: characters 4-30 : Cannot access to private field nmeInvalidateBounds
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/display/Shape.hx:29: lines 29-33 : Field nmeGetGraphics has different visibility (public/private) than superclass one
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/display/Shape.hx:36: lines 36-50 : Field nmeGetObjectUnderPoint has different visibility (public/private) than superclass one
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/display/DisplayObject.hx:299: characters 6-30 : Cannot access to private field nmeGetGraphics
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/display/DisplayObject.hx:323: characters 48-73 : Cannot access to private field _topmostSurface
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/display/Sprite.hx:38: lines 38-42 : Field nmeGetGraphics has different visibility (public/private) than superclass one
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/display/DisplayObjectContainer.hx:212: lines 212-222 : Field nmeBroadcast has different visibility (public/private) than superclass one
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/utils/ByteArray.hx:441: characters 59-65 : Unknown identifier : length
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/utils/ByteArray.hx:441: characters 68-76 : Unknown identifier : position
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/utils/ByteArray.hx:446: characters 9-21 : Unknown identifier : littleEndian
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/utils/ByteArray.hx:453: characters 2-14 : Unknown identifier : littleEndian
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/utils/ByteArray.hx:453: characters 2-14 : Invalid assign
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/utils/ByteArray.hx:35: characters 19-28 : Unknown identifier : allocated
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/utils/ByteArray.hx:122: characters 2-14 : browser.utils.ByteArray has no field length
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/utils/ByteArray.hx:122: characters 17-32 : browser.utils.ByteArray has no field allocated
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/utils/ByteArray.hx:260: characters 12-25 : browser.utils.ByteArray has no field position
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/utils/ByteArray.hx:263: characters 9-22 : browser.utils.ByteArray has no field position
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/utils/ByteArray.hx:265: characters 25-38 : browser.utils.ByteArray has no field position
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/utils/ByteArray.hx:274: characters 67-80 : browser.utils.ByteArray has no field position
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/utils/ByteArray.hx:278: characters 27-40 : browser.utils.ByteArray has no field position
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/utils/ByteArray.hx:279: characters 88-101 : browser.utils.ByteArray has no field position
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/utils/ByteArray.hx:283: characters 27-40 : browser.utils.ByteArray has no field position
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/utils/ByteArray.hx:284: characters 27-40 : browser.utils.ByteArray has no field position
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/utils/ByteArray.hx:285: characters 109-122 : browser.utils.ByteArray has no field position
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/browser/net/URLLoader.hx:150: characters 37-48 : browser.utils.ByteArray has no field length
```

I noted that ever since I upgraded nme to version 3.5.5, have these kinds of problems started to appear. It is not only happening with nme-runnermark, but in general, with almost any nme project that I try to build an html5 version out of. My next attempt would be to get rid of the current version of nme, and try with an older one.

Anyway, I wanted to know if anyone else is experiencing similar problems

Comment: This might be an issue with the latest haxe3 release and interpolarity with nme. In the console can you type 'haxe' and report the output (I'm guessing version 2) and it would be helpful to go directly to the nme mailing list, as it's more likely they're already know about this issue.  http://www.nme.io/community/mailing-list/

Answer (score 0):

NME 3.5.5 requires Haxe 2.10 or latest. Download and install it and it should be fine.